# How to save a PIL ImageGrab() img?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want know how to save an `ImageGrab()` from Pillow 5.0.0,

I use the Pycharm and my code is:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image

m1 = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
Image.save(m1)
```

but the image is not saved.

Comment: How about `m1.save()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.save()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) is an attribute of image.  You need to save like:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image

m1 = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
m1.save('test_image.png')
```