# How can I see what did PIL.ImageGrab.grab() captured from a screen?

Tags: python, windows, python-imaging-library

I'm using pyautogui to automate some browser process on Windows. To get data from screen I do screenshot grab with ImageGrab from Pillow. Then I do OCR with Tesseract module pytesseract.
I know how to grab just a part of a screen and then do OCR and import data into my database. It works fine most of the time.
However (as always :-) ) there are cases when a garbage comes out.
I am pretty sure I grabed the right area from the screen but am not 100% sure.
Therefore it would be nice if I'd be able to see what did Pillow grabed from screen.

Does pillow make any temporary files on file system? I was searching in C:\Users\XXXX\AppData* and found nothing.
I can see a variable in PyCharm:
`screen = <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=245x21 at 0x252D4D090C8>`
but I cannot see anything like an image inside.

How can I see what is the result of a Pillow Grab action?

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: A screenshot only copies from the screen buffer, so no temporary files are created. Save the image manually using Pillow's Image.save. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592620/how-to-save-a-pil-imagegrab-img).

Comment: Use `screen.show()` to see it on screen, or `screen.save('grab.png')` to save a file on disk.

Comment: Thanks for hints Mark and Ken. Both works really nice. I appreciate it.